# Fastest way to process this array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am looking to go from:

```
array($ID => array (name => $name, created => $timestamp))
```

e.g

```
[5632][name] = martin
[5632][created] = 131232342
[6742][name] = paul
[6742][created] = 131232312
[6321][name] = peter
[6321][created] = 131232311
```

to an array of ids ordered by creation like

```
[0] = 6321
[1] = 6742
[2] = 5632
```

What is the fastest way to achieve such in PHP?

Comment: Does the datasource not allow for ordering?

Comment: It does, however due to the complexity of the query I store the data in the users session when they login to my app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function sort_by_date($a, $b)
{
  if ($a['created'] == $b['created']) return 0;
  return ($a['created'] < $b['created']) ? -1 : 1;
}

$array = array(...);
uasort($array, "sort_by_date");
$ids = array_keys($array);
```

[`uasort`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) lets you sort an array by using a custom function while maintaining keys. [`array_keys`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) returns an array containing the keys of another array.

Comment: would this be any faster

function sort_by_date($a, $b)
{
  return strnatcmp($a['created'], $b['created']);
}

Comment: You could benchmark it, but my guess would be that `strnatcmp` would be slower (especially if your created keys are already numbers)

Comment: You were correct. Your script managed 1 million iterations in 7 seconds on my server where as strnatcmp took around 9.

Answer (score 1):

Why go through the effort of sorting the entire array of arrays, when you just want the ids?

```
$times = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
    $times[$key] = $item['created'];
}
asort($times);
$ids = array_keys($times);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$new_array = krsort(array_keys($your_array));
```

Comment: -1 (1) this does not work (2) you should not pass the result of a function to `ksort()` (3) `ksort()` returns a boolean